# Query string from C# using UNION - VarChar to Numeric error

Tags: c#, sql, code-behind

I've got the following line of code in C# Code Behind:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(CIT_NBR)) AS Decimal(12,2)) AS CIT_NBR 
FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation 
WHERE CUST_NUM = '" + TBAccountNum.Text + "' 
UNION '00.00'
FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation 
ORDER BY CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(CIT_NBR)) AS Decimal(12,2)) DESC";
```

This worked perfectly before I added the UNION piece, but I need this now because this SQL is populating a dropdownlist and the users want this "default" value.

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  The exact error I'm getting is:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

CIT_NBR is a VarChar. That's the only column. It's being converted into a Decimal(12,2) because when it's written to the new table, it's stored that way. Don't ask, I have no control over the back end... So, I need to add the value 00.00 and I don't know how to do that within a SQL string. I tried using double-quotes, it didn't like it. I tried using single quotes, it gave me the above error.

And yes, I know about the SQL injection risk, but I'll fix that once this actually works.  :o)

Comment: could it be that you are not doing the `UNION` correctly..? have you looked at any of the `SQL Tutorials on Union` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unions-clause.htm

Comment: That WHERE applies only to the second part of the UNION. Is this correct?

Comment: this is only a SQL question, not really anything to do with C#.  It would be like tagging this Windows because you're using a Windows OS.

Comment: @DanAndrews - Well, since it uses a SQL string within C#, it's quite different from straight-ahead SQL Server q\because of the way you need to wrap it in quotes.

Comment: @Steve - The WHERE actually only applies to the first part.  I've moved that around, but still have the same error.

Comment: This question was posted previously and closed.

Comment: @JohnnyBones your problem is in the query.  I suggest going to SSMS and resolving that first and then "wrap it in quotes".  Or even better, make a stored procedure.  Or even better than that, use LINQ / Lambda.  To most of us, it isn't "quite different"

Comment: @JonathanWood - Not by me.  Where is it, and does it deal with adding new values that don't exist in a table?  I'm not UNION-ing 2 tables here, I'm adding values that don't exist in any table.  This is an old trick I used in Access to add a default value to a dropdown, I assume it will work in SQL as well.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: How did you know the other question, which was deleted, had to do with "UNION-ing 2 tables"?

Comment: @JonathanWood - Because every question I found had to do with union-ing 2 tables.  I'm not a n00b here, I did my due dilligence before asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
string strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(CIT_NBR)) AS Decimal(12,2)) AS CIT_NBR 
FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation 
WHERE CUST_NUM = '" + TBAccountNum.Text + "' 
UNION 
SELECT 0.0
ORDER BY CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(CIT_NBR)) AS Decimal(12,2)) DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy!  Worked perfectly!